# Setting uid bit when mounting a drive in WSL causes unexpected results for other users

Tags: linux, windows, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Mount a drive like this, substituting 1000 for any user ID you want (except 0 for the purposes of this example):

`sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata,uid=1000`

Now, under the drive file system, run this command:

`sudo touch example.txt`

You will see that example.txt is owned by user 1000 and not root! This is not good, to understate things. It means, for example, that web server processes that have access to the drive will create files that are owned by user 1000 (or whatever you set) and not the user the web server is configured to run as. I discovered this in trying to get a LEMP stack to run WordPress on my C: drive.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Is it a WSL bug?

Answer (score 1):

After [communicating with the kind folks at the WSL GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4954), I solved my problems by moving all the mount settings into the `automount` section of `/etc/wsl.conf`, unmounting the C: drive and rebooting my computer. Basically a "turn it off and on again" solution, but it worked.